# Sending file with POST request to java servlet service

Tags: java, json, post, geoserver

I try to send a JSON file with a POST request to my geoserver. There runs my jar file as OWS Service (Java Servlet).

**Service:**

```
 public void upload(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String fileName = request.getHeader("fileName");
    File saveFile = new File(SAVE_DIR + fileName);               
    InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);  
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    System.out.println("Receiving data...");     
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }  
    System.out.println("Data received.");
    outputStream.close();
    inputStream.close();     
    System.out.println("File written to: " + saveFile.getAbsolutePath());   
    }
}
```

**Test Java:**

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?request=upload&service=GeoRestTransfer&version=1.0.0");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("fileName", "test.json");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
mapper.writeValue((OutputStream) wr, json); //JSONObject
wr.flush();
wr.close();
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
```

**Test Curl:**

```
curl -d "@test.json" -X POST "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?request=upload&service=GeoRestTransfer&version=1.0.0"
```

**JSON FILE *test.json*:**

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

---

**EDIT1:**

**New Test:**

I send the same JSON String in the Header to my Service with `conn.setRequestProperty("fileContent", jsonString);`, read this header out an write it to my file and it works. But why it doesnt work with the body?

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?request=upload&service=GeoRestTransfer&version=1.0.0");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("fileName", "test.json");
conn.setRequestProperty("fileContent", jsonString);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
mapper.writeValue((OutputStream) wr, content);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
```

---

**Problem:**

If I send this POST request with the java or curl I always get the error.

**Error:**

> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not { (position: START_DOCUMENT seen {... @1:1)

If I try it with an empty post body it works and it create a empty file. 
I can send like my new test the content with the header and this works too. 
Is it impossible to send the jsonobject in the body to an OWS service with post ? Or why i get this Error ?

Comment: Likely invalid json file, please post it too.

Comment: @CrazySabbath add JSON to question

Comment: What's `content` in `mapper.writeValue((OutputStream) wr, content);` ?

Comment: It would help to know what you are trying to achieve. If I were to guess, are you trying to append to json file? if so, this is not the way to go about it.

Comment: @CrazySabbath content is the JSON string from the file

Comment: i edit it to better varname `json`